# Typescript interpretation in Atom IDE

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, atom-editor

I'm having problems with the Atom IDE. It seems to me that the interpretation of other types of libraries, like Jquery, is not well accepted by the Typescript interpreter of the Atom.

Does anyone know if in Atom, the procedure is different?

At VSC, the interpretation is perfect. Already on the Atom, sucks!

Note: I already have Atom IDE and Typescript installed on the Atom.

### tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "outDir": "app/js",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "module": "system",
        "strictNullChecks": true

    },
    "include": [
        "app/ts/**/*"
    ]
}
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "alurabank",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "compile": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "server": "lite-server --baseDir=app",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run watch\" \"npm run server\""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.42",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: The question is very clear. I'm having problems with Atom when interpreting Typescript. On the right side is the VSC interpreting calmly, already to the left side, the Atom generates an unexpected error.

Comment: Do I need to repost my previous comment? Did you read my link?

Comment: I believe you are having a misunderstanding of the issue, and the big ones. I was clear in showing an image, and of course also in my question.

Comment: Could you please also provide contents of your tsconfig.json and some of your custom classes, e.g. NegociacoesView, otherwise it will be quite hard to provide any help. My current guess is that you might have some mix of module/non-module files, but we'll need to see more code to understand the problem.

Comment: Okay. I edited the post and added the two main configuration files.